# sideloaded windows 8 app crashing on Windows 8.1 and not installing on Windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, sideloading, windows-10

I am sideloading a dev package on windows 8.1 and on Windows 10.
On Windows 8.1 The app crashes as soon as it launches

> Faulting application name: XXXX.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54bd196d
>   Faulting module name: twinapi.appcore.dll, version: 6.4.9879.0, time stamp: 0x54585458
>   Exception code: 0xc000027b
>   Fault offset: 0x0000000000042bff
>   Faulting process id: 0x1d18
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d0359c520d8180
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\XXXXX\XXXXX.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
>   Report Id: 8fee8d71-a18f-11e4-830a-0050b662bf5b
>   Faulting package-relative application ID: App

And on Windows 10 it does not install saying

> error 0x80070020: Creating file \?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\XXXXX\Assets\SplashScreen.scale-100.png failed.

Any pointers to the solution would help

Comment: capture a crashdump of the exe with procdump from sysinternals (procdump -ma -i C:\dumps) and analyze it with Windbg: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-64-Windows-81-Store-App-Crash-c000027b

Comment: were you able to debug the crash?

Comment: How to get the .cab file? I am installing this on a testers device by running it through powershell

Comment: run the procdump command on the PC/tablet where you get the crashes. This configures Procdump as Postmortem debugger and creates dumps in C:\dumps. Open the dmp files from C:\dumps in Windbg

Comment: these crashes are happening on devices which are not in my control so all I can do is ask the particular person to share the crash dump with me. Is there any way which they can get the crash dump or .cab file and share?

Comment: ask the person to use procDump to generate the dumps. The person should compress the dumps as zip/RAR/7z, upload it to OneDrive and send you the link. Downlaod the compress file, expand it and open the dmp with Windbg.

Comment: did the person generate the dmp file? Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: I uploaded the app on store and can get the exception report from there now :) thnks